# Output number of Wordpress posts remaining until a post milestone is reached

Tags: posts, widgets

Some time ago there was a Wordpress plugin (Post Countdown) that created a widget to display how many posts there were still to be published before a milestone was reached. As of PHP8 it no longer works. Mind you it hasn't been updated for 10 years either.

A sample output was: "There are 600 posts until the 1000th post appears"

The means to do this was to get the current number of posts published on a blog and then subtract that number from the milestone post.

The plugin is more advanced than that, but the general idea seems simple enough.

Is there a simple code that can be inserted into an HTML or text widget to display this information?

Thanks for any help on this, it's appreciated from a newbie to coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can get the total number of posts from the `X-WP-Total` response header from the `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/` endpoint, e.g. using `fetch()` in Javascript or `apiFetch` from `@wordpress/api-fetch` module in a custom block.

Since number of fetched posts doesn't affect the `X-WP-Total` header, we can use `posts_per_page` as `1` and only get the post id field with `_fields`, to reduce the payload.

We might also create a dynamic block, including this kind of PHP:

```
$total = (new \WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 1 ) ) )->found_posts;
```

for the total posts part.

An older way was to use e.g. a custom shortcode `[remaining]` that outputs the
number of remaining posts:

```
add_shortcode( 'remaining', function( array|string $atts ) :string {
    $milestone = 1000; 
    $total     = (new \WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 1 ) ) )->found_posts;
    return sprintf( '%s', $total > $milestone? 0 : $milestone - $total );
} );
```

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, really appreciate it!

Comment: Glad to hear it helped