# Display the progress of post achievement with percentage against target in wordpress dashboard

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, shortcode

I have a cpt called "movie", and I set a target for writers to make 50,000 posts in 6 months. The question is... can I make a percentage of the results of the number of recent posts against the target, and how to display it through a shortcode?

For example: "total posts are 50% of target."

Is there any way to display that with a shortcode? Please help.

Comment: you wouldn't use a shortcode to display that inside WP Admin itself, it's far easier and simpler to call the function that displays the percentage directly instead of creating a shortcode that calls it, then constructing a shortcode string dynamically and asking WP to render it. The percentage part is easy as that's just math, it's counting the number of `movie` posts created in the last 6 months when there are going to be tens of thousands of posts that will be problematic

Comment: any solutions? plugins?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Output number of Wordpress posts remaining until a post milestone is reached](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/416005/output-number-of-wordpress-posts-remaining-until-a-post-milestone-is-reached)

Comment: the output that I expect is a percentage, is it possible?

Comment: yes, but that would be basic arithmetic that has nothing to do with WordPress e.g. something like this `$percentage = ( $found_posts / $target_posts ) * 100;`

Answer (score 1):

Here are my thoughts, which include both a shortcode and a direct function to display the post progress in the WordPress dashboard/admin area:

1. **Creating a Custom Shortcode:**

   You can create a custom shortcode to display the post progress on your WordPress site using the following code:

   ```php
   function post_progress_shortcode() {
       $post_type = 'movie';
       $target_count = 50000; // Set your target post count here

       $args = array(
           'post_type' => $post_type,
           'post_status' => 'publish',
       );

       $query = new WP_Query($args);
       $post_count = $query->found_posts;

       if ($post_count > 0) {
           $percentage = ($post_count / $target_count) * 100;
           $percentage = round($percentage, 2); // Round to 2 decimal places
           return "Total posts are {$percentage}% of the target.";
       } else {
           return "No posts found.";
       }
   }
   add_shortcode('post_progress', 'post_progress_shortcode');
   ```

   Usage: You can use the `[post_progress]` shortcode anywhere in your content to display the progress. This will allow you to display these statistics on the frontend of your website wherever you like.
2. **Function for Dashboard/Admin Area:**

   If you want to display the post progress directly in the WordPress dashboard/admin area, you can add the following code to your theme's `functions.php` file or a custom plugin file:

   ```php
   function display_post_progress() {
       $post_type = 'movie';
       $target_count = 50000; // Set your target post count here

       $args = array(
           'post_type' => $post_type,
           'post_status' => 'publish',
       );

       $query = new WP_Query($args);
       $post_count = $query->found_posts;

       if ($post_count > 0) {
           $percentage = ($post_count / $target_count) * 100;
           $percentage = round($percentage, 2); // Round to 2 decimal places
           echo "<p>Total posts are {$percentage}% of the target.</p>";
       } else {
           echo "<p>No posts found.</p>";
       }
   }

   // Hook the function to display in the dashboard
   function add_post_progress_dashboard_widget() {
       wp_add_dashboard_widget(
           'post_progress_widget',
           'Post Progress',
           'display_post_progress'
       );
   }
   add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'add_post_progress_dashboard_widget');
   ```

   This will add a widget titled "Post Progress" to the WordPress dashboard displaying the progress.

Now you have two methods to display post progress, one as a shortcode for content and the other as a dashboard widget for the admin area. You can use either method depending on your preference.

Comment: I would avoid providing a free copy paste solution and focus on explaining _how_ and _why_ it works. The asker and other readers may not understand the solution, forcing them to return if any minor change is needed. Remember basic programming knowledge is assumed on the site, you can assume everyone reading knows beginner level PHP